# Will My Archer Tower Defend In Clan War During Their Upgradation?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Will my archer tower defend in clan war during their upgradation?

Answer (score 4):

No, upgrading does not affect war bases. If the upgrade finishes before the battle day begins, the upgrade will be applied. Otherwise, the defence will function as it will before the upgrade.